# Flink: How to write DataSet to a variable instead of to a file

Tags: scala, apache-flink

I have a flink batch program written in scala using the DataSet API which results in a final dataset I am interested in. I would like to get that dataset as a variable or value (e.g. a list or sequence of String) within my program, without having to write it to any file. Is it possible?

I have seen that flink allows for collection data sinks in order to debug (the only example in their doc is in Java). However, this is only allowed in local execution, and anyway I don't know its equivalent in Scala. What I would like is to write the final resulting dataset after the whole flink parallel execution is done to a program value or variable.

Answer (score 3):

First, try this for the scala version of collection data sink:
    import org.apache.flink.api.scala._
    import org.apache.flink.api.java.io.LocalCollectionOutputFormat;

```
 .
 .
val env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

// Create a DataSet from a list of elements
val words = env.fromElements("w1","w2", "w3")

var outData:java.util.List[String]= new java.util.ArrayList[String]()
words.output(new LocalCollectionOutputFormat(outData))

// execute program
env.execute("Flink Batch Scala")
println(outData)
```

Second, if your dataset fits in memory of single machine why do you need to use a distributed processing framework? I think you should think more about your use case! and try to use the right [transformations](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/batch/dataset_transformations.html) on your dataset.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Sorry for the misunderstanding, the initial dataset does not fit in memory, but the dataset resulting as an answer after applying all the transformations does (it is something like finding the maximum of the groups given some conditions from a very large list of items).

Comment: But sometimes in stream environment it wont emit the expected result, wonder why

Comment: got the answers, cause it async, maybe, the solution is the one that i posted below

Answer (score 0):

I used flink 1.72 with scala 2.12. And this is a **streaming** prediction using SVM that i wrapped up in Model class. I think the most correct answer is using `collect()`. It'll return Seq. i got this answer after searching for hours. i got the idea from [Flink Git - Line 95](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-examples/flink-examples-batch/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/examples/java/misc/CollectionExecutionExample.java)

```
var temp_jaringan : DataSet[(Vector,Double)] = model.predict_jaringan(value)
temp_jaringan.print()

var temp_produk : DataSet[(Vector,Double)] = model.predict_produk(value)
temp_produk.print()

var result_jaringan : Seq[(Vector,Double)] = temp_jaringan.collect()
var result_produk : Seq[(Vector,Double)] = temp_produk.collect()

if(result_jaringan(0)._2  == 1.0  && result_produk(0)._2 == 1.0 ){
  println("Keduanya")
}else if(result_jaringan(0)._2  == 1.0  && result_produk(0)._2 == -1.0){
  println("Jaringan")
}else if(result_jaringan(0)._2  == -1.0  && result_produk(0)._2 == 1.0){
  println("Produk")
}else{
  println("Bukan Keduanya")
}
```

It may vary based on other version. cause after using and searching flink material like a mad dog for weeks even months for my final project as graduation requirement, i know that this flink develepment projects need more documentation and tutorial, especially for beginners like me.

anyway, correct me if im wrong. Thanks!